# How to avoid use of copy-constructor and move constructor in C++

Tags: c++, atomic, copy-constructor

I'm getting some problem of classes implementation for a C++ project.
Here's the code:

```
A {
    private:
    std::atomic<bool> flag;    
    std::atomic<int> value;

    public:
        A(){}
};

class B{
    private:
    std::vector<A> vett;

    public:
        B(){}
        void add_A(A a){
            vett.push_back(a);
        }
};

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    B b{};
    return 0;
}
```

I know that compiling errors are caused by **std::atomic**, cause it isn't copy-constructible, nor copy-assignable and class A has std::atomic as attributes.
Unfourtunately class A should be a thread-safe class, so I need to use **std::atomic** or **std::mutex** (that is also not copyable).
By reading other question, to overcome this problem I may create a wrapper struct for an std::atomic, but in this way atomicity would be compromised, so what would be another possible solution?

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vett`? but really depends of what you want...

Comment: Do you really need to copy `a`? Can you have the vector in `B` contain references or pointers?

Comment: Should `A` be copyable or moveable? You can just copy current values of atomic variables in move/copy ctors/assignments

Comment: In C++20, you can use non-atomic types (which may be put into a vector) and then access them via _atomic references_ ([`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref)) when necessary.

Comment: Every methods of any instance of A, can be invoked only by class B.
I just would like to create a certain number of instances of A inside B, and these instances of A can't be shared among different instances of B.
Given those prerequirements I don't need a copy costructor or a move constructor of A

Answer (score 1):

`A` can be made both copyable and moveable by explicitly copying the current values of the atomic members. Of course none of those methods are thread-safe.

```
struct A{
    std::atomic<int> m_member{false};

    A()=default;
    A(const A& other):m_member(other.m_member.load()){}
    A(A&& other):m_member(other.m_member.load()){
        // Move other members
    }
    A& operator=(const A& other){
        if(&other!=this){
            // De-init current members.
            this->m_member=other.m_member.load();
            // Copy other members.
        }
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator=(A&& other){
        if(&other!=this){
            // De-init current members.
            this->m_member=other.m_member.load();
            // Move other members.
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```